# Django EmailField model not checking invalid email in Model

Tags: python, django

I have been working with Django for quite some time, but I am surprised to see that Django EmailField doesn't validate email addresses before inserting data into my database.

I am currently using Django Rest Framework and below is my code.
This is HTTP request to the server:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/contact/ HTTP/1.1
content-type: application/json


{
    "email" : "bad--//sample@gmail.com",
    "name" : "hi",
    "message" : "Hello"
}
```

My Django model:

```py
from django.db.models import Model, TextField, DateTimeField, EmailField


from smavity.helpers.fields import NameField

# Create your models here.

class Contact(Model):

    name = NameField(max_length=20)

    email = EmailField()

    message = TextField()

    date = DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

My Serializer class:

```py
from rest_framework.serializers import ModelSerializer

from .models import Contact

class ContactSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:

        model = Contact

        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: According to the docs,, django checks if the value passed is valid email or not. Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.EmailField

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come to notice that EmailField follows certain RFC standard so you have to build your own validator using regex.

Comment: Django now supports it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Django's validators](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/validators/). Check it from the documentation.

Comment: Does that mean that Django EmailField doesn't validate data before insertion?

Comment: I have added validator to the model, still yet it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you check the GitHub of Django? There are some snippets on : https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/core/validators.py#L168-L180